# FK in a Laravel polymorphic relation

Tags: mysql, laravel, polymorphism

Hi I'm using a polymorphic relation in laravel: [official doc](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relation)

Basically, the idea is in to be able to invite to several object a user ( Tournament, Team, Asociation, Club, etc...)

So, my "Invitation" table is like:

```
(id, object_id, object_type, user_id, other_fields)
```

Where object_type is the name of the class ( 'App\Tournament','App\Team', etc) and object_id the FK.

But this way, I don't know how to use object_id as a MySQL ( MariaDB ) Foreign Key, is it posible???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible, the whole idea behind polymorphism is that the `object_id` field is not pointing to a single other table.

You can't say that `object_id` reference `id` on table 'X' because that's not always the case.

Comment: yep, I know, but that way, I'm losing integrity in my DB. So, I'm fan, but not a big one ... I thought there were a workaround in mysql for this kind of common stuff

Comment: You can still check integrity "by hand" using a transaction while you are checking every thing...

Comment: The transaction stuff is not necessary here I think but before deleting a row in you r Invitation table, you can check manually if anything else have a dependency to it then throw an exception if so. In your case, with what you gave to us, it seems to just be a pivot table (sort of) so I'm not even sure you have to check for dependencies.. What are you afraid of exactly?

Comment: I'm not afraid, I just like to have integrity in my DB. If I don't have a FK in this field, so it become posible to have trash data...